# UVa 11402 Runtime Error

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I am trying to solve the problem [11402- Ahoy Pirates](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&category=&problem=2397) on UVa Online Judge. The code is supposed to build a segment tree on some specified information and perform update or query operations. My C++ Code runs fine on my system. But I receive a runtime error on submission. Since my array size can go upto ~ 3000000 elements, I am afraid whether array of such large size can result in runtime error. Any ideas?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <queue>
#include <set>
#include <sstream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
typedef long long ll;

struct Node{
    char upd;
    // 0 - Buccaneer pirates
    // 1 - Barbary pirates
    int p[2];
    Node(){
        p[0] = 0;
    p[1] = 0;
        upd = ' ';
    }
    void update(char cmd){
        if (cmd == 'I'){
            switch(upd){
                case ' ': upd = 'I';break;
                case 'I': upd = ' ';break;
                case 'E': upd = 'F';break;
                case 'F': upd = 'E';break;
            }
        }
        else if (cmd != ' '){
            upd = cmd;
        }
    }
    void S(){
        int temp;
        switch(upd){
            case 'I': temp=p[0]; p[0]=p[1]; p[1]=temp; break;
            case 'E': p[1]+=p[0]; p[0]=0; break;
            case 'F': p[0]+=p[1]; p[1]=0; break;
        }
        upd = ' ';
    }
};

Node tree[4028000];
char pirates[1024010];

void buildTree(int index, int i, int j){
    if (i>j)
        return;
    if (i==j){
        if (pirates[i] == '0'){
            tree[index].p[1] = 1;
            tree[index].p[0] = 0;
        }
        else{
            tree[index].p[0] = 1;
            tree[index].p[1] = 0;
        }
        tree[index].upd = ' ';
        return;
    }
    int mid = (i+j)/2;
    buildTree(2*index+1,i,mid);
    buildTree(2*index+2,mid+1,j);
    tree[index].p[0] = tree[2*index+1].p[0] + tree[2*index+2].p[0];
    tree[index].p[1] = tree[2*index+1].p[1] + tree[2*index+2].p[1];
    tree[index].upd = ' ';
}

void update(int index,int i,int j,int l,int r,char c){
    if (i == l && j == r){
        tree[index].update(c);
    }
    tree[2*index+1].update(tree[index].upd);
    tree[2*index+2].update(tree[index].upd);
    tree[index].S();
    if (i == l && j ==r)
        return;
    if (l>j || r<i || l > r)
        return;
    int mid = (i+j)/2;
    update(2*index+1,i,mid,l,min(r,mid),c);
    update(2*index+2,mid+1,j,max(l,mid+1),r,c);
    tree[index].p[0] = tree[2*index+1].p[0] + tree[2*index+2].p[0];
    tree[index].p[1] = tree[2*index+1].p[1] + tree[2*index+2].p[1];
}

int query(int index,int i,int j,int l,int r){
    if (l>j || r<i)
        return 0;
    tree[2*index+1].update(tree[index].upd);
    tree[2*index+2].update(tree[index].upd);
    tree[index].S();
    if (i == l && j == r){
        return tree[index].p[0];
    }
    int mid = (i+j)/2;
    int b1 = query(2*index+1,i,mid,l,min(mid,r));
    int b2 = query(2*index+2,mid+1,j,max(mid+1,l),r);
    return b1+b2;
}

int main(void){
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    for(int z=0; z<t; z++){
        int m,len=0,T,q,querycnt=1;
        char str[64];
        scanf("%d",&m);
        for(int i=0; i<m; i++){
            scanf("%d %s",&T,str);
            for(int j=0; j<T; j++){
                int length = strlen(str);
                for(int k=0; k<length; k++){
                    pirates[len] = str[k];
                    len++;
                }
            }
        }
        buildTree(0,0,len-1);
    scanf("%d",&q);
        printf("Case %d:\n",z+1);
        for(int i=0; i<q; i++){
            char cmd;
            int l,r;
        scanf(" %c %d %d", &cmd, &l, &r);
            if (cmd == 'S'){
                int ans = query(0,0,len-1,l,r);
                printf("Q%d: %d\n",querycnt++,ans);
            }
            else{
                update(0,0,len-1,l,r,cmd);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you test the array size hypothesis with a simpler program?

Comment: Now that is *really* convoluted C with all of those `#define`s. It is really bad form to shorten everything to one letter abbreviations. The methods are already abbreviated enough. (`atoi`? Really? What does `a` even stand for?).

Comment: @juanchopanza I tested my hypothesis on my system and the program worked perfectly.

Comment: @Linuxios I know it's not a pretty C++ code and I would appreciate f you could point out the mistake in this code :)

Comment: @gibraltar: Simple. Get rid of *all* of the defines. Get rid of everything from `#define s` to `#define sz`. And get rid of `CLEAR`. For anyone who comes to look at this code, it is just unclear and cryptic. And do you really want your code to look either like BASIC or like the assembly generated by OSX GCC?

Comment: @Linuxios Corrected. Does it look better now?

Comment: @gibraltar: Hugely! Good job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the solution lies in the following two statements

```
tree[2*index+1].update(tree[index].upd);
tree[2*index+2].update(tree[index].upd);
```

In both the above statements, the index of the array tree can reach upto 2*(2*N+1) (overflow operations) where N is the largest size of the input. In the above question N = 1024000. Since the size of the array tree is less than 4*N, the program will produce segmentation fault in case of huge inputs. A solution to the above problem could to check the bounds of the index before accessing the array or making the array large enough to handle all the overflow update operations.